# ORACLE Table Loading Speed

Tags: oracle

This is a new issue that I haven't run into before.

I have a table that at one point contained over 100k records, it's an event log for a dev environment.

it took up to 10 seconds to load the table (simply clicking on it to view the data in the table).

I removed all but 30 rows and it still takes 7 seconds to load.

I'm using Toad, and it gives me a dialog box that says "Statement Processing..."

Any ideas?

The following are some select statements and how long they took

```
select * from log;  21 rows in 10 secs
select * from log where id = 120000; 1 row in 1 msec
select * from log where user = 35000; 9 rows in 7 sec
```

The id is the pk, there is no index on the user field.

I have a table view that contains all of the fields sitting ontop of this table as well and it runs just as slow.

Comment: Can you try a simple `select * from table` and see how long it takes?

Comment: What do you understand under *I load the table* exactly?

Comment: Updated my question with some of the selects that I've tried and the results.

Comment: @Rene... When I click on the table to view the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you issue a "select * from event_log_table", then you are scanning the entire table with a full table scan. It has to scan through all allocated segments to see if there are rows in there. If your table once contained over 100K rows, then it has allocated at least the amount of space to be able to hold those 100K+ rows. Please see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/schema.htm#sthref2100

Now if you delete rows, the space is still allocated to this table, and Oracle still has to scan all space. It works like a high water mark.

To reduce the high water mark, you can issue a TRUNCATE TABLE command, which resets the high water mark. But then you'll lose ALL rows.

And there is an option to shrink the space in the table. You can read about it and its preconditions here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#sthref5117

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: considering that it is test data in a dev environment, there is no damage done by simply truncating the table... this table appears to be a candidate for shrinkage, but it gives me an invalid tablespace or segment error.  I'm not finding any good documentation for that error though.  any other documentation you might have that would help fixing that particular error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type... row movement is enabled

Comment: I can only reproduce the error when shrinking space, not when truncating the table. An ORA-10635 appears when trying to shrink space when the table is compressed. You may want to uncompress first.

Comment: Thats it! i ran across that but It didn't actually click.  I didn't have a reason to believe that the table was already compressed but at some point in time it appears that is had been.

Answer (score 0):

I would better understand this if you started off with a 100M records table. But just in case, try running Oracle stats. If this doesn't help, drop and recreate indices on that table.

Comment: Im looking at the stats... and I'm not sure really what I'm looking at, but something is deffinately not right.  A couple of things stick out.. the table currently has 21 rows... the stats say NUM_ROWS | 12  ?? Is this something?

Comment: @Patrick: Probably nothing. Stats reflect an estimate of the number of rows last time they ran. I would be worried if it still showed 100K. Do you have any indices on this table?

Comment: Yes and I have dropped and re-added them to no avail.